# Buried drainage pipe

Tags: drainage

So I just had a drainage pipe installed to convey water from the gutter drain in the back of my house to the front of my house. We had our first rain yesterday and the gutter drainage system is working well, however, I noticed there is an area that is fairly saturated and I think it’s because of the water runoff from my neighbors roof. The pipe that we installed was triple walled HDPE solid pipe. Now I am wondering if there should’ve been some perforated pipe at the base of that little slope there. What should I do? Install some perforated pipe with drainage rock and soil fabric? Or install some kind of catch basin? Or just leave it?

[image]

Comment: or talk with your neighbour and ask if they want to tie that roof drain into your pipe as well.

Comment: I don't think perforated pipe would do anything for your saturated area (at least, what I think is your saturated area based on the pic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your neighbor's downspout appears to stop a foot off the ground, and there is a washout path down the slope from there to your problem area.  In most (all?) jurisdictions, this is a code violation.  One is generally required to direct the roof water from one's property into the sewer system and to prevent it from flowing onto a neighbor's property.
Your neighbor may have disconnected the downspout to "solve" his backup problem caused by a collapsed or clogged underground drain line.  If so, he would need to fix it by doing essentially what you did:  install or replace the line.
While it might seem neighborly to offer to let him tie into your line, it would not likely be code compliant, nor save much money, and could lead to complications and legal issues when either of you sells their house.
(I also noticed the gray area on the neighbors' brick overlay that looks like water damage.  They may have a clogged gutter/downspout that accounts for it and for some of the waterflow onto your property.  They should welcome your drawing it to their attention.)